# Cursor Starts in Middle of TextBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

The cursor on a TextBox that I have created begins on the center-left side of the of the TextBox, but I would like for it to begin at the top-left side of the text box.

[image]

Being somewhat of a novice with Xaml, I'm not sure how to adjust this.

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         TextWrapping="Wrap"
         AcceptsReturn="True"
         Grid.Column="2"
         Grid.Row="1"
         Grid.RowSpan="2"
         Margin="15, 5"
         Width="214" />
```

Comment: Does you custom style changes `VerticalContentAlignment` to Center or template vertically center aligns `ScrollViewer`? Try setting `<TextBox ...  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">`

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! Something very simple...